# how to read value from application.yml in Java Spring with variable name?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

Im trying to read a specific value (in a controller class) and I have got something  like this:

```
@Value("${userId.site.%s}")
private String userIdSite;
```

but "site" is a variable, it can be one value or another.

In Application.yml Ive got:

```
userId:
  site:
    mla: 123
    mlb: 456
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: you can read it as Map right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with the @Value annotation and are free to make the site data a map:

```
userId:
   site: '{
       mla: 123,
       mlb: 456
   }'
```

And in your code define userIdSite as a map.

```
@Value("#{${userId.site}}")
private Map<String, Integer> userIdSite;
```

Then use your 'variable' to obtain the value from the map. Another slightly different alternative is to use @ConfigurationProperties which could read the map
using:

```
userId:
   site:
       mla: 123,
       mlb: 456
```